# Excel VBA - Loop & IF statement results not static and updating on each new run

Tags: vba, excel

I have racked my brain for to long on this simple problem that I cannot figure it out at this point. 
The situation: 
I have 2 columns, D and I. Column D is filled down to X# of rows. 
I need to search for a string on each cell in D:X cell and based on the IF loop assign a value to I:X cell

The problem: 
With each loop the value that is stored in the cells I-1 through I-X is updating with the most current value. So at the end of the third loop the values in I1-I3 are all Unknown. Any help is appreciated. 
Old Code

```
 Sub Country()
    'Variables
    Lastrow = Worksheets("SFDC").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lastrow2 = Worksheets("SFDC").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'check the rows for values
    If lastrow2 > 1 Then
        lastrow2 = 0
        Else
    End If
    'Code will run until the last value it reached
    Do While lastrow2 <> Lastrow
        Set Check = Range("D2:D" & Lastrow)
        For Each Cell In Check
            If InStr(Cell, "ANZI-") Then
                Range("I2:I" & cellvalue).Value = "ANZI"
                lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
            ElseIf InStr(Cell, "US-") Then
                Range("I2:I" & cellvalue).Value = "US"
                lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
            Else
                Range("I2:I" & cellvalue).Value = "Unknown"
                lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
            End If
        Next
    Loop
End Sub
```

New Code, Now the values are changing but its only being assigned to the initial cell I:2. But if I add +1 to the cellvalue like the previous codethen it still overwrites the previous values.

```
Sub Country()
'Variables
lastrow = Worksheets("SFDC").UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Code will run until the last value it reached
Set Check = Range("D2:D" & lastrow)
cellvalue = 2
For Each Cell In Check
    If InStr(Cell, "ANZI-") Then
        Range("I2:I" & cellvalue).Value = "ANZI"
    ElseIf InStr(Cell, "US-") Then
        Range("I2:I" & cellvalue).Value = "US"
    Else
        Range("I2:I" & cellvalue).Value = "Unknown"
    End If
    cellvalue = cellvalue + 1
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Edit for clearer comment: The for each cell loop does the same action regardless of whether a match was found so in effect is redundant.

Comment: 1) All the `If...` cases do the same thing; what's the point? 2) Your columns are not A and B but, it looks like D and I, right?

Comment: Correct. I just thought simplifying it would be easier to read. I updated the code to what the output should be.

Comment: You code is a little bit confusing. The `Lastrow` and `lastrow2` are using the same logic (guess you modified it for this post).  You can move `lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1` outside of the `IF` so you don't need to repeat that line three times.  But to be honest, loop through all cells is not recommended.  Maybe you can try to use `ActiveSheet.Cells.Find` to speed up the process.

Comment: Imm pretty sure the problem is the Range("I2:I" & cellvalue).Value = "ANZI" 
and that the values are getting rewritten that way.

What I need it to do is if i'm on D2 and "ANZI-" is there i need the value "ANZI" assigned to I2
@ian0411

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so dumb.

```
Sub Country()
'Get # of rows on worksheet
lastrow = Worksheets("SFDC").UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Setting variable for the For Loop
Set Check = Range("D2:D" & lastrow)
'will be used as a counter for the cell the return will be placed
cellvalue = 2

'Code will run until through each cell until the last value it reached
For Each Cell In Check
    'if the string is in the D cell then the value will be written to the I cell
    If InStr(Cell, "ANZI-") Then
        Cells(cellvalue, "I") = "ANZI"
    ElseIf InStr(Cell, "US-") Then
        Cells(cellvalue, "I") = "US"
    Else
        Cells(cellvalue, "I") = "Unknown"
    End If
    cellvalue = cellvalue + 1
Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `Do...Loop` because the `For...Next` is already doing the job for you. And, besides, it is better to do `lastrow2 < Lastrow + 1` instead of `lastrow2 <> Lastrow`

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that you got your answer but since I have already worked on, this is for your reference.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Country()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Check As Range
Dim rowNum As Long
Dim cell

'Get # of rows on worksheet
lastRow = Worksheets("SFDC").UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Setting variable for the For Loop
Set Check = Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
'will be used as a counter for the cell the return will be placed

'Code will run until through each cell until the last value it reached
For Each cell In Check
    rowNum = cell.Row()
    'if the string is in the D cell then the value will be written to the I cell
    If InStr(cell, "ANZI") Then
        Range("I" & rowNum) = "ANZI"
    ElseIf InStr(cell, "US") Then
        Range("I" & rowNum) = "US"
    Else
        Range("I" & rowNum) = "Unknown"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```